# when overload the operator >, < and ==, can we use class member function not the friend function?

Tags: c++

as I see the return type is `bool`
can we use it as member function rather than make it friend function in a class?

such as :
`friend bool operator >(String& string1, String &string2);`

can we just write as:
`bool operator>(string &string2);`

Comment: Sometimes, but it's impossible for `bool operator > (const char* string1, String &string2);`, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we just write as: bool operator>(string &string2);

Not with consistent results, **no**.

Making those comparison functions *member functions* can break code that would have otherwise worked when they were free functions.

Function **parameters** are subject to *implicit conversions* that **can not** be applied to `this`.

With member function comparators, if there existed some type `X` that can be implicitly converted to your `String` type,

```
String() == X()
```

would be well-formed, but

```
X() == String()
```

would not.

Comment: Some of us don't want implicit conversions all over the place, so "you should avoid it" is subjective and ought to be marked as such.

Comment: Maybe the desire for implicit conversions is subjective, but surely operator transitivity is pretty much universally appealing, at least for relational operators.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... TartanLlama's comment appeared as I typed, but basically *yes*.  I'm not a fan of implicit conversions myself, but making those conversions inconsistent is what I'm suggesting to avoid.

Comment: Well I caution straying too far from the question into opinion territory, making it appear as if the answer is "no" when it is in fact "yes".

Answer (score 1):

Prefer free-standing functions to class members. In particular, I find non-member, non-friend < a more suitable in general case.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

You could simply have *tried it*.

Furthermore, this has nothing whatsoever to do with the return type being `bool`.

Comment: then why all the textbooks overload these operators(>, < and ==) as friend? just curiosity:)

Comment: Non-member operators also allow type conversions on the lhs, which members don't.